# Eclipse android Error setting focus to : org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl Manager.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i keep getting this error when i try to run my application, problem is i deleted my manager class, so i don't know where the error is coming from. I suspect my try, catch exception in my main activity, but tried removing it and my app still wasn't opening, this is the code...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button logbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logbutton);
    Button regbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regbutton);
    logbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    regbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(args.getId()){
        case R.id.logbutton:
            String email = em.getText().toString();
            String pword = pw.getText().toString();
            boolean didItWork = true;
            MySqlDB details = new MySqlDB(this);
            try {
                details.open();
                boolean data = details.checkData(email, pword);
                details.close();

                if (data == true) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainHomepage.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                didItWork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("oops!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {
                if (didItWork) {
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Yay!!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Successful!");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.regbutton:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainRegister.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

below is the logcat

```
03-03 12:58:47.354: W/GAV2(29238): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
03-03 12:58:47.354: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.354: I/GAV2(29238): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
03-03 12:58:47.354: W/ActivityManager(690): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found
03-03 12:58:47.364: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.364: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.364: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.374: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.374: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.374: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.384: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.384: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.384: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.394: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.394: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.394: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.404: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.404: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.404: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.404: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.404: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.414: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.414: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.414: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.414: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.424: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.424: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.424: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.434: W/qdhwcomposer(204): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 74 ms
03-03 12:58:47.434: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.434: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.434: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.434: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.444: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.444: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.444: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.454: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.454: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.454: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
03-03 12:58:47.464: D/chromium(16048): Unknown chromium error: -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your buttons declared at the class level?

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Button logbtn;
    private Button regbtn;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        logbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logbutton);
        regbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regbutton);
        logbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        regbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

And can we please see the logcat output?

Comment: i added the logcat and i tried declaring the buttons but that didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

**It is a bug in eclipse **

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357608

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385973

Nothing except for "killing a debug session during a Java (reference) search".